# Magento 2 Meta Description on Admin Product Edit page not working

Tags: magento2, product, adminform

My data is not showing on product edit page admin.
Its shows error like below[image]

Console showing me ReferenceError: showSpinner is not defined in https://demo.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js line 2624 > Function

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Please check for error log

Comment: Nothing is showing in error log

Comment: did you find any solution, I am facing same problem.

Comment: @H_Parekh, Please update your store version to latest.